# Dehydrating herbs - leaves vs. stems

Tags: food-preservation, herbs, dehydrating

I use my dehydrator to dehydrate herbs such as parsley and dill. I use low temperature (95 F = 35 C) to preserve the taste. The dark-green leaves are usually completely dry after several hours, but the light-green stems remain slightly wet.

At one time, I made the mistake of putting everything together in a jar; it caught the mold in several days and I had to trash it.

I tried to cut the stems from the leaves and dehydrate them separately, but it turned out to be a very tedious task as each piece has a different length so I had to cut each piece separately.

What do you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both parsley and dill has a lot of flavour in the stems.

Freezing is good, as suggested by Joe, but maybe chopping the stems with a machine/grinder prior to drying might help the process.  Discard them if the stems are really woody of course.

Comment: My wife loves the stems, so I think this is the answer I will use.

Answer (score 4):

Don't dry the stems is the answer, simply discard them. I strip the leaves off the stems either before or after drying for the same reasons you describe - they don't dry well. For many herbs there isn't as much flavor in the stems as the leaves, so less value in drying them anyway.

Comment: You can toss the stems in when you're next making stock.  (freeze 'em if it'll be a while before your next batch), so that they don't go to waste.